# Can't Log back in after timeout

Tags: timeout

I have no coding experience whatsoever.  I am using some code that someone gave me so that my login will timeout.  However, once it times out, I can't immediately log back in.  A few days later, if I try again, I can.  Can anyone help me on how I can modify this code so that I can immediately log in after it times out?
Thank you so much for you help!

This is what I have in place:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logintime'])){
$_SESSION['logintime'] = time();
}else {
if(time() > $_SESSION['logintime'] + 15 * 60){
unset($_SESSION['username']);
}else{
$_SESSION['logintime'] = time();
}
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   header('Location: ./mealplans.php');
   exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that altering this code will have the effect you want. However you could play with the bit that says '15 * 60' - that will mean 15 minutes.